# How to configure Fiddler's Autoresponder to "map" a host to a folder?

Tags: regex, proxy, fiddler

I'm already using Fiddler to intercept requests for specific remote files while I'm working on them (so I can tweak them locally without touching the published contents).

i.e. I use many rules like this

```
match:    regex:(?insx).+/some_file([?a-z0-9-=&]+\.)*
respond:  c:\somepath\some_file
```

This works perfectly.

What I'd like to do now is taking this a step further, with something like this

```
match:    regex:http://some_dummy_domain/(anything)?(anything)
respond:  c:\somepath\(anything)?(anything)
```

or, in plain text,

> Intercept any http request to 'some_dummy_domain', go inside 'c:\somepath' and grab the file with the same path and name that was requested originally. Query string should pass through.

Some scenarios to further clarify:

```
http://some_domain/somefile       --> c:\somepath\somefile
http://some_domain/path1/somefile --> c:\somepath\path1\somefile
http://some_domain/path1/somefile?querystring --> c:\somepath\path1\somefile?querystring
```

I tried to leverage what I already had:

```
match:    regex:(?insx).+//some_dummy_domain/([?a-z0-9-=&]+\.)*
respond:  ...
```

Basically, I'm looking for `//some_dummy_domain/` in requests. This seems to match correctly when testing, but I'm missing how to respond.

Can Fiddler use matches in responses, and how could I set this up properly ?

I tried to respond `c:\somepath\$1` but Fiddler seems to treat it verbatim:

```
match:   regex:(?insx).+//some_domain/([?a-z0-9-=&]+\.)*
respond: c:\somepath\$1

request:  http://some_domain/index.html
response: c:\somepath\$1html        <-----------
```

Comment: Did you try regex backreference syntax like `\1`, `$1` etc?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I did, I forgot to mention it. Amended the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is your use of `insx` at the front of your expression; the `n` means that you want to require [explicitly-named capture groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Explicit), meaning that a group `$1` isn't automatically created. You can either omit the `n` or explicitly name the capture group.

From the Fiddler Book:

**Use RegEx Replacements in Action Text**

Fiddler’s AutoResponder permits you to use regular expression group replacements to map text from the Match Condition into the Action Text. For instance, the rule:

Match Text: `REGEX:.+/assets/(.*)`
Action Text: `http://example.com/mockup/$1`

...maps a request for `http://example.com/assets/Test1.gif` to `http://example.com/mockup/Test1.gif`.

The following rule:

Match Text: `REGEX:.+example\.com.*`

Action Text: `http://proxy.webdbg.com/p.cgi?url=$0`

...rewrites the inbound URL so that all URLs containing `example.com` are passed as a URL parameter to a page on `proxy.webdbg.com`.

Match Text: `REGEX:(?insx).+/assets/(?'fname'[^?]*).*`

Action Text `C:\src\${fname}`

...maps a request for `http://example.com/‌assets/img/1.png?bunnies` to `C:\src\‌img\‌1.png`.

Comment: Ah I see, I failed at R-ingTFM. Omitting the `n` from my last `match` did the trick.